# Do you only get one chance at casting a spell?

Tags: arkham-horror

There is an Encounter card that was drawn that caused Stamina damage. The player has a spell that negates any Stamina damage at the cost of one Sanity if roll is successful.

If that roll fails is the player able to re-roll until they are successful or lose all Sanity?

In addition to that, if the current Environment effect is Planetary Alignment which reduces all spell Sanity cost by one it would make the Sanity cost zero. In this case would the player be able to roll until successful with infinite chances?

Comment: It's best to name the actual spell, since in general the wording on cards matters. I'm guessing you're talking about Flesh Ward, which reads "Any Phase: Cast and exhaust to ignore all Stamina loss being dealt to you from one source. Discard this spell if the Ancient One awakens."

Comment: I believe that's it. I will have to double check when I get home from work and edit it in.

Comment: Okay. In this case, I don't think it matters, since all the spells say "cast and exhaust", but in general it's helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you get only once chance.

The key phrase is "cast and exhaust". An exhausted card can't be used again until it's un-exhausted during the next turn's upkeep. And the spell is exhausted whether or not you succeed at casting it.

The rules are a little bit fuzzy on this, but [this official FAQ](http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/437-official-answers-from-kevin-wilson/) has a pretty clear answer:

> Does an unsuccessful attempt to cast a spell still exhaust it?
>
> Yes.